# Algorithm for adding black bars to an image

Tags: javascript, image

I am trying to write a function that adds black bars to an image such as in the example below:

[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Crknd.jpg) and [after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HIbJ.jpg)

I have the following code. I believe the algorithm is correct, however, it only works for certain images and certain values. For example, it does work when the "cuts" variable is equal to 7 and the resolution of the uploaded image is 1920x1080, however it doesn't for any other values other than 7, 1 or 2. Why?

Also, if you think of a better algorithm please share it with me.

```js
rectangleButton.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if(loadCounter === 4) {
    var cuts = parseInt(text.value);
    text.value = null;
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var divisions = (2*cuts)+1;

    var lines = canvas.height;
    var columns = canvas.width;
    console.log(canvas.height);
    console.log(canvas.width);
    console.log(divisions);
    var k = 1;

    var scannedRectangleImage = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    var scannedRectangleImageData = scannedRectangleImage.data;

    for(k = 1; k < 2*cuts; k = k+2) {
    for(var i = k*lines/divisions; i < (k+1)*lines/divisions; i++)
    {
        for(var j = 0; j < columns; j++)
        {
                scannedRectangleImageData[i*4*columns+4*j] = 0;
                scannedRectangleImageData[i*4*columns+4*j+1] = 0;
                scannedRectangleImageData[i*4*columns+4*j+2] = 0;
        }
    }
    console.log(k + " < " + 2*cuts);
    }

    scannedRectangleImage.data = scannedRectangleImageData;
    ctx.putImageData(scannedRectangleImage, 0, 0); }
    else
    {
        alert("Image upload is not ready");
    }

})
```

Comment: `var i = k*lines/divisions` will often not be an integer: For 1080 'lines' only 1, 2, 4, 7, and 13 'cuts' will give a whole number for i (and loops only work properly with integers). I can't follow fully your algorithm but think you'll need to calculate your loop counter differently, perhaps by using `Math.floor()` on the loop counter calculations.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, it turns out that was the problem. Converting those values to integers made it work.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it

```
function drawImage(image) {
  const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  canvas.setAttribute('width', image.width);
  canvas.setAttribute('height', image.height);

  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

  const stripeCount = document.getElementById('stripeCount').value;
  const sectionCount = 2 * stripeCount + 1;
  const stripeHeight = Math.ceil(image.height / sectionCount);

  const imageData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  for (let i = 0; i < stripeCount; i++) {
    drawStripe(2 * i + 1, stripeHeight, imageData.data, canvas.width);
  }

  ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
}

function drawStripe(stripeIdx, stripeHeight, imageData, imageWidth) {
  const lineStart = stripeIdx * stripeHeight;
  const dataStart = lineStart * imageWidth * 4;
  const dataLength = stripeHeight * imageWidth * 4;

  for (let idx = dataStart, l = dataStart + dataLength; idx < l; idx += 4) {
    imageData[idx] = 0;
    imageData[idx + 1] = 0;
    imageData[idx + 2] = 0;
  }
}
```